# Add class property to protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a protocol that have a variable. And class that conform to that protocol should use it like "normal" variable. What i want is something like:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
var foo: Int
}

class A {}
extension A: MyProtocol {
  var foo: Int!
}
```

Code above not compile, i only want to show point i want to achieve.

I ended up with this, but i suppose there must be better way:

```
enum NextController {
  case AuthSelection
  case Main
}

protocol SmsEntryPresenterProtocol {
  var nextController: NextController { get set }
}

class SmsEntryPresenter {

  var _nextController: NextController!
  weak var view: SmsEntryViewProtocol?

}

extension SmsEntryPresenter: SmsEntryPresenterProtocol {

  var nextController: NextController {
    get {
      return _nextController
    }
    set {
      _nextController = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide variable  get or set like  `var foo: Int {get set}`

Comment: Extension has not role in your code!! What you want to do with extension

Comment: No, there isn't other way. You can't add stored properties in extensions. The way you did it uses computed property, which is allowed.

Comment: @mag_zbc but it look kind of ugly for me

Comment: Can you modify your original class. Like, can you add protocol conformance to the class not via extension?

Comment: you should use `nextController: NextController` as get only property (computed property) where you can confirm to any class and just return then next view controller. You don't need to store `_nextController` . as per my opinion

Comment: It was a design decision to not allow adding stored properties in extensions - it's because stored properties need, well, storage, and that would change the memory structure of the class - and extensions shouldn't do that.

Comment: @mag_zbc in Obj-C there was an easy approach, because property itself was encapsulation of logic i presented above..

Comment: BTW, if you just change `var _nextController: NextController!` to `var nextController: NextController` in `SmsEntryPresenter` then you can remove `get set`  from the extension and it will simplify to this. `extension SmsEntryPresenter: SmsEntryPresenterProtocol { }`

Comment: @Kamran have you tried it? It's not work.. i did try like that first.

Comment: It will work but you have to provide an initializer to initialize `nextController`.

Comment: @Kamran then please provide complete compiling example as an answer.

Comment: The “problem” is only that the protocol requires a non-optional property, whereas the class has an implicit unwrapped optional property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this as below,

```
class SmsEntryPresenter {

    var nextController: NextController = .Main
    weak var view: SmsEntryViewProtocol?

}

extension SmsEntryPresenter: SmsEntryPresenterProtocol {}
```

Comment: yes it work, though providing default value not the best option for me..

Comment: Yeah, in that case you have to introduce an initializer. In any case you have to initialize this property because it is declared non-optional in the protocol. This looks simpler to me.

Comment: is that possible to create an optional value in protocol without initialize it in class that implement it?

Comment: Yeah, this way you won’t need to assign with any default value